# MonoTouch.Dialog RadioGroup summary not updating

Tags: xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

I am trying to create a very basic RadioGroup with MonoTouch.Dialog. After I select an item in the list of options and go back to the main view, the RadioGroup still shows that the default value is selected. However, when I go to select another item, the previous value I selected is still checked. I have looked at several examples online and none of them seem to be doing anything special to cause the main view to reflect the newly selected value. What am I doing wrong/missing?

Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
using System;
using MonoTouch.Dialog;
using MonoTouch.Foundation;
using MonoTouch.UIKit;

namespace TestApp
{
    public class MainSettings : DialogViewController
    {
        public MainSettings (UIViewController parent) : base (UITableViewStyle.Grouped, null)
        {
            Root = new RootElement ("Settings")
            {
                new Section("Cellular Network") 
                {
                    new RootElement("Refresh Data", new RadioGroup(2))
                    {
                        new Section()
                        {
                            new RadioElement("Every 5 Minutes"),
                            new RadioElement("Every 15 Minutes"),
                            new RadioElement("Every 30 Minutes"),
                            new RadioElement("Hourly"),
                            new RadioElement("Manually")
                        }
                    }
                }
            };
        }

        public override void ViewWillAppear (bool animated)
        {
            NavigationItem.RightBarButtonItem = new UIBarButtonItem ("Close", UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, delegate
            {
                DismissModalViewControllerAnimated (true);
            }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks,
Randy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's even more obvious than I originally thought. I wasn't calling **base.ViewWillAppear**!